# How to remove one specific duplicate named column in columns of a dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have a  sample dataframe df with columns as:

```
  a b c a a b b c c 
0 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2
1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2
. . .
. . .
```

I want to remove the duplicate columns named with only 'a' and keep other as same
The expected o/p is:

```
  a b c b b c c 
0 2 2 1 1 1 2 2
1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2
```

Comment: This removes all duplicate columns but I want the specific column 'a' and remaining all same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a general solution to drop any duplicates of a column, no matter where these columns are in the dataframe and what the content of these columns is.
First we get all column indexes for the given column name and drop the first occurrence. Then we "substract" these indexes from all indexes and return the remaining columns:

```
to_drop = 'a'
dup = [i for i,v in enumerate(df.columns) if v==to_drop][1:]
df = df.iloc[:, list(set(range(len(df.columns))) - set(dup))]
```

Result:

```
   a  b  c  b  b  c  c
0  2  2  1  1  1  2  2
1  2  2  2  1  2  1  2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df = df.T.reset_index().drop_duplicates().set_index('index').T
del df.columns.name
```

> Exp

since the column a has only dupe values, so we can simply transpose with reset index

```
df.T.reset_index()


  index  0  1
0     a  2  2
1     b  2  2
2     c  1  2
3     b  1  1
4     b  1  2
5     c  2  1
6     c  2  2
```

Apply drop_duplicate on above df and only the dupes will get removed. It serves the purpose in those instances too where there are more than one column which has dupe value

**Output**

```
   a  b  c  b  b  c  c
0  2  2  1  1  1  2  2
1  2  2  2  1  2  1  2
```

Comment: care to explain.. ? @Codenewbie

Comment: I really need an exp mate

Comment: This is based on value, I think OP wants to remove duplicated 'a' column names. Not sure why he accepted it as answer

Comment: This will drop any duplicate columns, not just 'a'. It only works by chance in the example because the 'b' and 'c' columns have different values.

Comment: @Stef both are correct, but since OP specified that he wants only 'a' column to be dropped so i figured others might not be a duplicate, also even if it drops other dupe columns it serves the purpose doesn't it

Comment: as @Stef mentioned , what if the other columns too have same values??